# Is binding data in template from external object a bad practice?

Tags: angular, data-binding

Let's say that I have a store (a big singleton object) where I keep the general application state. This store is injected to components if needed. However, there are components which use only one property from the store, and use it for conditionals in their templates (as read-only of course).

Is there a preferred practice here? Should I use the property directly from injected store

```
class MyComponent {

    constructor(private store: Store) {}
}

// template

<div *ngIf="store.someFlag">...</div>
```

or should I create private property in the component and then use it in template?

```
class MyComponent {

    someFlag: boolean;

    constructor(private store: Store) {
        this.someFlag = store.someFlag;
    }
}

// template

<div *ngIf="someFlag">...</div>
```

I'm mostly concerned about performance - does accessing a data from a big object in template affect the performance of Angular change detection cycles?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I prefer using store.someFlag directly as that property may get changed and it will be immediately reflected on the page whereas if you assign it to a local variable, that variable doesn't change overtime (unless you do something).
Assigning to variable makes sense if you plan on changing that value locally and don't want the change be propagated back to store. I do it when I want to get my app Date to apply to this screen initially, but screen can change already local date back and force as user pleased.

And second, if you plan to use store in template, make sure you make it public in constructor (not private) as it will not pass stricter production rules.

```
class MyComponent {

    constructor(public store: Store) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out a different issue I see with the approach: You tie the components to the way you have implemented the global state. By doing that, you closely couple them.

Say you want to change the structure of your global state. For example, you want to move an object one level down in the state's hierarchy. With your approach, you will have to touch each and every component, possibly multiple times per component.

I would recommend to leave the components as stupid as possible. Give them an actual object that they can read or change as an `@Input()`. Let them work on it. Add an `@Output()` when/if the object changes.

Like this, you more clearly separate concerns: The components just need to know how to deal with one specific class, not with the overall state.

Comment: But what if I need that state in approximately in all components, will it not become tedious and complex to maintain /@Input property and /@Output event?

Comment: If it is a "big singleton object" as mentioned in the question, and you need that big singleton object in every component, I think something is wrong with the architecture. In that case, yes, it would be tedious and complex, but that would merely be a pointer to a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it is true that all components would not require same "big singleton object"  but not for components with level of hierarchy more than 3 . Are there any other possible ways to share data to 4-5 level down the hierarchy of components other then Input/Output ?

Comment: You can, of course, provide larger parts of your state to your components. It is always a trade-off where you have to find the best option for your concrete use case. I would simply avoid passing the same giant state object to every component and by that lose a) flexibility, b) testability, c) overview.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyComponent {

    constructor(public store: Store) {}
}

// template

<div *ngIf="store.someFlag">...</div>
```

This will be the better option. As if you make a local copy of that variable then on change detection it may happen that your value when changed from different module/component will not be reflected in this component.